# trying to add discount that users can see

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to add a discount to my products so users can see the discount product with a discount number but I have some problem I think my idea is right but it do not work well here is my codes

```
 $get = mysqli_query($conn," SELECT * FROM products WHERE quantity >0 GROUP BY product_name  LIMIT ".$this_page_first_result.','.$result_per_page);
$number_of_results=mysqli_num_rows($get);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($get)) {
    $id = $row['product_id'];
    $name = $row['product_name'];
    $type = $row['type'];
    $img = $row['img'];
    $weight=$row['weight'];
    $price=$row['product_price'];
?>


<article  style="background-color: white; border-left-width: 2px; border-bottom-width: 2px;margin :4px;   box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 2px #65b7c2;
">
  <img src="adminpanel/product_img/<?php echo $img?>" alt="" style="height:13rem;width:13rem;">
  <h3 ><?php echo $name;?></h3>
  <?php 
         $dis=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT discount FROM products WHERE product_name='$name'");
         $rowdis=mysqli_fetch_array($dis);

         $discount=$rowdis['discount'];
         if (mysqli_num_rows($dis)==1) 
         {
            ?>
            <h4>$<?php echo $discount ?></h4>
            <?php
         }
         else
         {
         ?>

<h4>$<?php echo $price ?></h4>
<?php
}
    ?>
```

so I have a filed named discount if that filed has a value show me the value if not show the product price it shows me the discount value for the product but when it does not have a value it should show the normal price but it does not show only the last item in the database shows the normal price here is a pic to be more clear other values shows 0 can anyone tell me where did I went wrong 
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLkwa.png)

Comment: What's the exact problem with the given code? It does not make use of that file named `discount` after all

Comment: @NicoHaase it is not a file i accepted an edit he changed it to file it is a filed named discount if that filed has a value show me that instead of the normal value but it does not do that

Comment: Replace `if` condition with this - ` if (mysqli_num_rows($dis)==1 && !empty($discount)) `

Comment: What do you mean by "filed"? Can you add all clarification to your question by editing it?

Comment: @AlokMali thanks it solved my problem you can add it i will accept it as a solution

Comment: @NicoHaase i meant database fields i think it is called fields am i wrong ?

Comment: @johnalbert, ok I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace your if condition with below one -

```
<?php if (mysqli_num_rows($dis)==1 && !empty($discount)){ ?>
    <h4>$<?php echo $discount ?></h4>
<?php } else { ?>
        <h4>$<?php echo $price ?></h4>
<?php } ?>
```

Because you have some rows which have `$rowdis` but that are empty(value 0).